# POSTing forms to external URLs fails w/RoutingError when testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, braintree

I have an integration test for a Rails app that POSTs to Braintree's Transparent Redirect API. Basically the test fills in a form with valid data, and simply expects the correct response back. I'm not trying to test every single one of Braintree's validations - just want one test to make sure that my form works in most cases.

However, my form is throwing this error:

```
1) Braintree CreditCard integration creates a credit card on Braintree and locally
Failure/Error: click_on 'Add card'
ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [POST] "/merchants/XXX/transparent_redirect_requests"
```

The form_for helper in question looks like:

```
=form_for :credit_card, :params => @result && @result.params[:credit_card],
:errors => @result && @result.errors.for(:credit_card),
:builder => ApplicationHelper::BraintreeFormBuilder,
:url => Braintree::TransparentRedirect.url,
:html => {:autocomplete => "off"} do |f|
```

The relevant line seems to be Braintree::TransparentRedirect.url - perhaps in the testing environment this gets trunctated/loses the relevant host information? Not so! Outputting page.html for the test shows the following:

`<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com:443/merchants/XXX/transparent_redirect_requests" autocomplete="off" method="post">`

So why does the test appear to try to hit /merchants... on my own server rather than posting the data to sandbox.braintreegateway.com, as the form's action attribute clearly states?

Also, manually duplicating the test procedure (fill in form with valid data, hit submit) works in both development and production.

Answer (score 2):

Rails integration tests send all requests to your rails app - the host portion of the URL is ignored.

You could probably do this with rspec request specs as long as you use a suitable capybara driver - the default `Rack::Test` has the same behaviour with respect to hosts, but something like Capybara-webkit or one of the selenium drivers might be different.